# Test a declined payment with Express Checkout using PayPal REST API

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

I have searched through the PayPal documentation, and I can't find a way to test a declined payment scenario using the REST API.

[I saw this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27919997/paypal-sandbox-negative-testing-of-subscriptions-with-rest-api) and it seems to indicate some test scenarios can be accomplished through the REST API, however, the answer is not immediately clear and my testing has not allowed me to produce a declined payment.

Here is what I've tried, with no success:

- I've enabled Negative Testing in the Sandbox Account Details for the Business / Payee account.
- I've run a number of transactions with different amounts (such as 105.34, 105.35, 105.39, among many others) as [per these instructions](https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/), but all payments complete successfully.

Perhaps I'm missing something. Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Negative testing is not available in REST API . Refer to https://developer.paypal.com/docs/classic/lifecycle/sb_error-conditions/ , you can test negative scenario in classic API express checkout.

Comment: Thanks for the response - since my integration is through the REST API using the classic API express checkout will not help. I'm not sure if you're from PayPal - if so, are there plans to add negative testing to the REST API? If so, any idea on the time frame? Thanks again.

Comment: Sure, we will submit this request to product team, but I am afraid there is no time frame for now. :)